# jquery como receber dados linha a linha num loop

Tags: php, jquery, loop, post

No ficheiro teste.php tenho:

```
<?php

echo "<input type='button' value='Envia' class='btenvia'/><br><br>";
echo "<div id='mostradados'></div>";

?>

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".btenvia").click(function(){

            $.post("dados.php", {opcao: 1 },
            function(info){

                $("#mostradados").html(info);

            });
        });
      });
     </script>
```

No ficheiro dados.php tenho por exemplo um loop com o for:

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++) {

    echo "linha ".$i."<br>";
}
?>
```

Como é que faço para que o loop apareça linha a linha na minha visualização, em vez de aparecer tudo de uma só vez. Estava a pensar em ajax mas não estou a ver como fazer.

Resultado no console:

```
linha 0<br>linha 1<br>linha 2<br>linha 3<br>linha 4<br>linha 5<br>linha 6<br>linha 7<br>linha 8<br>linha 9<br>linha 10<br>linha 11<br>linha 12<br>linha 13<br>linha 14<br>linha 15<br>linha 16<br>linha 17<br>linha 18<br>linha 19<br>linha 20<br>linha 21<br>linha 22<br>linha 23<br>linha 24<br>linha 25<br>linha 26<br>linha 27<br>linha 28<br>linha 29<br>linha 30<br>linha 31<br>linha 32<br>linha 33<br>linha 34<br>linha 35<br>linha 36<br>linha 37<br>linha 38<br>linha 39<br>linha 40<br>linha 41<br>linha 42<br>linha 43<br>linha 44<br>linha 45<br>linha 46<br>linha 47<br>linha 48<br>linha 49<br>linha 50<br>linha 51<br>linha 52<br>linha 53<br>linha 54<br>linha....
```

Comment: acho  que seria melhor você retornar  um json no seu php e ler ele com o ajax do jquery

Comment: Antes de `$("#mostradados").html(info);` coloca um `console.log(info);` e veja o que retorna no console. Se possível edite a sua  pergunta e inclua a informação do que é retornado.

Comment: No console log retorna todos os valores de uma só vez. Queria que retorna-se o valor após cada linha do loop, para não ter que esperar pelo resultado de todas as linhas.

Comment: Tudo bem. Apenas para fins de teste, poderia editar sua pergunta e colocar o que você viu no console?

Comment: Seu problema é de exibição (aparecer aos poucos é algum tipo de efeito visual) ou de desempenho (está lento pegar tudo de uma vez)?

Answer (score 1):

Bom você pode dar um split no breakline igual  no codigo abaixo

$(document).ready(function(){

```
    $(".btenvia").click(function(){

        $.post("dados.php", {opcao: 1 },
        function(info){

            var rt = info.split("\n");
            var count = 0;
            while( count <= rt.length){
                console.log(rt[count]);
                count++;
            }
        });
    });
  });
```

Mas recomendo você retorna um json e ler ele com o ajax do jquery muito mais eficaz